# maximum subarray with static struct return types

Tags: c, struct

I made maximum subarray algorithm, which something seems to be wrong with. Since C cannot return multiple values, function "maxarr" OR "maxcarr" is supposed to return three value-(start index, end index, and sum of it) in a static struct "rettype". However, those return value seems to be the same one(I have checked its memory adress, which was all same). I suppose that error occurs because static type variables are only declared once and do not be initialized more than one time, but I do not know how I can correct it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct rettype
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct rettype* maxarr(int i, int j, int* array);
struct rettype* maxcarr(int i, int j, int* array);
int main(void)
{
    int array[20];
    int temp = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int len = 0;
    struct rettype* ret;
    printf("Type length in.\n");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    while (num<len)
    {
        printf("%dth element: ", num);
        scanf("%d", &array[num]);
        num++;
    }
    ret = maxarr(1, len, array);
    printf("Maximum Subarray:\nfrom element %d to element %d with sum of %d\n", ret->a, ret->b, ret->c);
    return 0;
}

struct rettype* maxarr(int i, int j, int* array)
{
    static struct rettype retb;
    static struct rettype ret;
    struct rettype* fretr;
    struct rettype* fretc;
    struct rettype* fretl;
    int hi=j;
    int mid;
    int low=i;
    mid = ((hi + low) / 2);
    if (i == j) {//base case
        retb.a = i;
        retb.b = j;
        retb.c = *(array + i);
        return &retb;
    }
    fretl = maxarr(i, mid, array);
    fretr = maxarr(mid+1, j, array);
    fretc = maxcarr(i, j, array);
    if (fretl->c>fretr->c && fretl->c>fretc->c)
    {
        ret.a = fretl->a;
        ret.b = fretl->b;
        ret.c = fretl->c;
        return &ret;
    }
    else if (fretr->c>fretl->c && fretr->c>fretc->c)
    {
        ret.a = fretr->a;
        ret.b = fretr->b;
        ret.c = fretr->c;
        return &ret;
    }
    else
    {
        ret.a = fretc->a;
        ret.b = fretc->b;
        ret.c = fretc->c;
        return &ret;
    }
}
struct rettype* maxcarr(int i, int j, int* array)
{
    int mid = (i + j) / 2;
    static struct rettype ret;
    int a = mid;
    int b = mid+1;
    int risum = -9999;
    int lesum = -9999;
    int sum = 0;
    while (a-->i)
    {
        sum += *(array + a);
        if (sum>lesum)
        {
            lesum = sum;
        }
    }
    sum = 0;
    while (b++<j)
    {
        sum += *(array + b);
        if (sum>risum)
        {
            risum = sum;
        }
    }
    sum = 0;
    ret.a = a;
    ret.b = b;
    ret.c = risum + lesum;
    return &ret;
}
```

Comment: why are you returning a pointer to a static struct? C is able to return structs perfectly well.

Comment: `ret = maxarr(1, len, array);` --> `ret = maxarr(0, len-1, array);` ?

Answer (score 0):

you're using a `static` variable you're taking the address from to return to the caller.

In that case, you're sharing a same memory area for your return value, instead of creating separate ones.

Why not returning the *value* of the structure instead (C cannot return arrays, but can return structs, fortunately):

```
struct rettype maxcarr(int i, int j, int* array)
{
    int mid = (i + j) / 2;
    struct rettype ret;
    ...
    return ret;
}
```

(and drop `static` for an auto variable which is copied when returned)

Note that you'll have to apply this pattern to all your routines.

Answer (score 0):

[Maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)
[Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct rettype {
    int start;
    int end;
    int sum;
};

struct rettype max_subarray(int array[], int length);

int main(void){
    int array[20];
    int len = 0, num;
    struct rettype ret;

    printf("Type length in.\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &len) != 1){
        printf("invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(len > 20){
        printf("too long.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    for(num = 0; num < len; num++){
        printf("%dth element: ", num);
        if(scanf("%d", &array[num]) != 1){
            printf("invalid input.\n");
            len = num;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(len > 0){
        ret = max_subarray(array, len);
        printf("Maximum Subarray:\nfrom element %d to element %d with sum of %d\n", ret.start, ret.end, ret.sum);
    }
    return 0;
}

struct rettype max_subarray(int array[], int length){
    struct rettype ret  = { .sum = array[0] };
    struct rettype curr = { .sum = array[0] };

    for(int i = 1; i < length; ++i){
        if(array[i] < array[i] + curr.sum){
            curr.sum += array[i];
            curr.end = i;
        } else {
            curr.sum = array[i];
            curr.start = curr.end = i;
        }
        if(ret.sum < curr.sum){
            ret = curr;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```